# How do I work with a logo that has what seems like too many colors?

Tags: website-design, color-theory

The company I'm designing a site for has an logo that I must work with. All of my ideas for standard color palettes and layouts are challenged by this logo.. Most [good looking] logos I've worked with and seen have one, two, maybe three colors. This one has six. They look okay within the context of the logo, but I'm having a difficult time translating any of them into the rest of the design. The only thing that's been promising is use of mostly neutral colors, but this leaves the site looking a tad bit boring, in my opinion.

Does anyone have any tips for this sort of situation?

Edit: Thanks for the answers, guys. I'm not comfortable posting the actual logo, but I threw this together to give a better idea of what I'm working with as far as colors and their corresponding dominance-

[image: Logo]

I probably made the color combination sound worse than it actually is because I've been over-thinking this. My most recent design iteration came out pretty well, but it does incorporate DA01's one-color suggestion which I'll have to run by the client. That opens up a lot of options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bad/obnoxious logo is like a bad/obnoxious person. You have to segregate them from the general population before the wreak havoc on everything.

Some ideas:

- see if the company has a one-color variation of the logo (They *should* but may not)
- give it it's own 'space'. Put it in a horizontal white bar across the top of the web site
- give it some 'no mans land' padding. Like the previous idea, but more of a 'block'. Stick it on a white shape with plenty of space around each side to that it's not fighting with other elements near it.
- camouflage it. Can you overlay it on a photo? Move it to the bottom?

Answer (score 11):

As Thomas mentions, most websites will pick the main colors and use those, or go for a completely different (yet still simple) palette. These are some of the main examples I can think of.

Sites that use a related palette:

- [NBC](http://www.nbc.com/)
- [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/default.aspx)
- [Stuff](http://www.stuff.co.nz/)
- [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/)

Sites that use a completely different palette:

- [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en)
- [Olympics.org](http://www.olympic.org/)

It's difficult to come up with creative ways of working with your colors without seeing the actual logo, but I can almost say most sites you'll see will probably go for **white with one or two main shades.**

Comment: It's funny, I almost said something in my original post about logos that _do_ have many colors always seeming to span all the hues of the rainbow and all of your first set of links followed exactly that. Interesting!

Answer (score 3):

Pick two colors in the logo that stand out and work with them.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest.